# How to dynamically set the location of a SOAP address in a WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL file that I'm using the generate my Java code. The WSDL file has the following piece of code for SOAP address

```
<wsdl:service name="SomeService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:HttpBinding_SomeService" name="HttpBinding_SomeService">
            <soap:address location="https://www.someservice.com/testenv/SomeService?client_id=XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX&amp;client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX"/>
        </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I want the `<soap:address>` location to be changed dynamically. Is there a way I can do this using Java?

Answer (score 1):

this is the complete example with imports

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class WsdlDynamicPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            changePath();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | 
 TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void changePath() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException{
        String filepath = "path to wsdl\\demo.wsdl"; //Give your wsdl file path
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        Node address= doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:address").item(0);

        NamedNodeMap attr = address.getAttributes();
        Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("location");
        nodeAttr.setTextContent("new path to wsdl");

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way of doing that using `DocumentBuilder`, I have just given the syntactic lines just groom them with imports and try-catch

```
String filepath = "fakepath\\wsdl.xml"; //Give your wsdl file path
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

    Node address= doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:address").item(0);

    NamedNodeMap attr = address.getAttributes();
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("location");
    nodeAttr.setTextContent("Your new location here");

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

You can write this into a function and call it by passing the location as a parameter. And change the wsdl file dynamically.